# How do I consolidate a Sketcher line construct?

Tags: geometry

I have created a Sketcher sketch like that:

[image]

[image]

[image]

But I can't get it to become filled as I planned to:

[image]

Did I mess it up in such a way that it can't be used, or is there any way to still achieve what I want as I have the vertices where they should be?

I have uploaded the blend file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18ZFr645wgv90TORK0rLSQ0VcNhbmYNWe/view?usp=share_link).

Thank you for help.

Comment: You completely ignored the topology of the object and just made a bunch of overlapping rectangles with no regard to closed shape outlines or intersections. Software can't tell in from out.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamosI thought the software could figure it out. Is there any way to save the mesh?

Answer (score -1):

This will work. Taken from an answer for discord.

[image]

Comment: Answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating some steps and final result. See [How to write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), otherwise it may be converted to a comment.